# beaker: downgrade to 1.6.3 fails without error message

Tags: python, rhodecode

Since I am having problems with rhodecode (db problems when upgrading) I reverted rhodecode to an old version (1.3.6->1.5.1->1.3.6). Beaker is a dependency and should have been reverted to 1.6.3 but sticks to 1.6.4 - with no error message either during the Rhodecode downgrade or a manual attempt.

Manually trying to downgrade yields

```
server:~# pip install beaker==1.6.3
Downloading/unpacking beaker==1.6.3
  Downloading Beaker-1.6.3.tar.gz (52Kb): 52Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package beaker
Installing collected packages: beaker
  Found existing installation: Beaker 1.6.4
    Uninstalling Beaker:
      Successfully uninstalled Beaker
  Running setup.py install for beaker
Successfully installed beaker
Cleaning up...
server:~# pip freeze
Babel==0.9.6
Beaker==1.6.4
FormEncode==1.2.4
Mako==0.7.0
Markdown==2.1.1
MarkupSafe==0.15
Paste==1.7.5.1
PasteDeploy==1.5.0
PasteScript==1.7.5
[...]
```

So I am still at 1.6.4. Also dependent Rhodecode still stumbles upon this.

How to I downgrdae to 1.6.3? (Running on Ubuntu with Python 2.6.6.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens rarely that mixing easy_install and pip can lead to some odd issue.RhodeCode can work with 1.6.4, i recommend removing file requires.txt from RhodeCode.egg-info located in site-packages of your python installation or virtualenv directory